# Стилизованные теги формы - <select> - <option>

Tags: css

Как делают вот такие раскрывающиеся списки?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Конструкция HTML вроде как наверное будет примерно такая:

```html
<select size="1">
<option value="среднее">высшее</option>
<option value="среднее">среднее</option>        
<option value="Нет">Нет</option>    
</select>
```

Comment: Такое делают js библиотеками, например: https://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/

Comment: @АлександрСемикашев напишите ответ с примером. когда-нибудь такой вопрос повторится.

Comment: @Alex, Этот вопрос возникает на просторах SO стабильно раз в пол года минимум, а уж сколько таких вопросов на просторах интернетов .... и да, никакие новомодные css3 html5 за все время с того момента когда этот вопрос впервые был задан так и не смогли предоставить ничего нового по этой части, так что тут закрывать по идее надо, а не давать ответы ...

Comment: @MedvedevDev как ни странно ответа с chosen не найдено )

Comment: @Alex, Вот как появится вопрос "как с помощью chosen стилизовать?" тогда и нужен будет этот ответ .... а пока это общий вопрос с все теми же "используйте один из десятка плагинов, используйте вот такой велосипед" и прочее ... Если разрешать плодить однотипные вопросы только из-за того, что один из десятка ответов будет "не такой как у всех", то это будет просто свалка, где потом никто и никогда не найдет никакой полезной информации.

Comment: @MedvedevDev ни один новый ответ, если он является решением, не может быть лишним. Запретить задавать вопросы Вы не можете(как и никто другой), а отмечать дубликатом запросто, если Вы видите, что это дубликат. Но это не повод отказываться от новых ответов на заезженный вопрос.

Comment: Ответы на данный вопрос я встречал и в других местах. Например использовать плагин http://dimox.name/jquery-form-styler/ или https://select2.org/ . Но надеялся, что может быть что-то поменялось с тех времён.

Comment: @ikar да в принципе ничего не меняется. Даже если и будут решения на css3 и html5, то я не думаю что все браузеры будут поддерживать.

Answer (score 0):

Такое реализовать можно с помощью js/jquery библиотек. Например: https://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/

Вам необходимо скачать и подключить библиотеку на нужной странице.

Добавляем нужный select:

```
<select data-placeholder="Выберите страну..." class="select">
     <opton value="Russia">Россия</option>
     <opton value="Korea">Корея</option>
</select>
```

Потом добавляем js код:

```
$(".select").chosen();
```

Стилизовать уже можно с помощью CSS в файле chosen.css

А так на самом деле решений на StackOverflow куча, почти на 99% реализуется с помощью js.